# CA service management conect to rest_access but another tables not found in postman basic Auth

Tags: rest, broadcom

I connect to `http://localhost:8050/caisd-rest/rest_access` and status is 200 ok in postman but, I'm trying connect to

```
http://localhost:8050/caisd-rest/cnt
```

and the postman return 404 not found here the codes:
code snippet success to `rest_access`

```
<code>var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:8050/caisd-rest/rest_access");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("X-AccessKey", "2050397415");
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.Headers.Add("X-Obj-Attrs", "\*");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic U2VydmljZURlc2s6U0FkMjAyMSM=");
var content = new StringContent("", null, "text/plain");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

code snipett not workink to cnt

```
http://localhost:8050/caisd-rest/cnt

var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://localhost:8050/caisd-rest/cnt");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("X-AccessKey", "2050397415");
request.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
request.Headers.Add("X-Obj-Attrs", "\*");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic U2VydmljZURlc2s6U0FkMjAyMSM=");
var content = new StringContent("", null, "text/plain");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());<code>
```

I need to use in C# MVC application the tables CA service